# Java Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR returns week of the month

Tags: java, date, calendar

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        try {
            // your code goes here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
            Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
            String s = "12-12-2014";
            Date dte=sdf.parse(s);
            cal.setTime(dte);

            System.out.println( cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)+"");
        } catch (Exception e ) {}
    }
}
```

**Output is** `3`.

I am trying to get week of the year from a given date. I referred java docs but the `WEEK_OF_YEAR` should be in `50`.

Comment: have you tried printing cal (not a getter on a field, but the entire date) ?
Also: don't allow your code to swallow exceptions. How do you know it doesn't crash?

Answer (score 7):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` is wrong, see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Letter | Date or Time | Component | Presentation | Examples
>
> m | Minute in hour | Number | 30

It should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```